# The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict

Tags: oauth-2.0, token, refresh, spotify

using Spotify API and Flask I am trying to extend refresh_token validity. As a result, when I send a request to the server, I get this error:

```
*The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a Response.*
```

My code:

```
@app.route("/index")
def index():
    if time.time() > session['expires_in']:
        payload = session['refresh_token']
        ref_payload = {
            'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
            'refresh_token':session["refresh_token"]
        }
        header={'Authorization': 'Basic ' + '<CLIENT_ID>:<CLIENT_SECRET'}
        r = requests.post(AUTH_URL, data=ref_payload, headers=header)
    return r

@app.route("/q")
def api_callback():
    session.clear()
    code = request.args.get('code')

    res = requests.post(AUTH_URL, data={
        "grant_type":"authorization_code",
        "code":code,
        "redirect_uri":REDIRECT_URI,
        "client_id":CLIENT_ID,
        "client_secret":CLIENT_SECRET
        })
    res_body = res.json()
    session["token"] = res_body.get("access_token")#token
    session["expires_in"] = res_body.get("expires_in")#time
    session["refresh_token"] = res_body.get("refresh_token")#reflesh token
    return redirect("index")
```

https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token is accepted as AUTH_URL

Most likely the problem is very commonplace, but I can't think of a solution now. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. In my configurashion file i was create a veriable in which i encode my client_id and client_secret to base64 format:

```
ID_SEC = CLIENT_ID +':'+ CLIENT_SECRET
base64_encode = base64.b64encode(ID_SEC.encode()).decode()
```

After in the header i edit authorisation :

```
header={
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic {}'.format(base64_encode)
}
```

And send post requests:

```
r = requests.post(AUTH_URL, data=ref_payload, headers=header)
```